# Gradle: How to publish all subprojects with single command?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, maven-publish

I have a multi-module gradle project and I use maven-publish in the subprojects block. How can I publish all my subprojects in one command or is there a way to create a custom task? This is [My publish block](https://github.com/overfullstack/vader-root/blob/4cb4f460a09787cec8aad8647e9388182d297037/build.gradle.kts#L118). Thanks!

```
subprojects {
publishing {
    publications.create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
      val subprojectJarName = tasks.jar.get().archiveBaseName.get()
      artifactId = if (subprojectJarName == "vader") "vader" else "vader-$subprojectJarName"
      from(components["java"])
      pom {
        name.set(artifactId)
      }
        
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I see this works for small set of modules, is there any way to achieve with many modules
`gradle module-1:publish module-2:publish module-3:publish`

Answer (score 1):

`gradle publish` at root project level worked! I was trying `gradle :publish` before  (Notice the`:`)